# What does option private module do? Does add in can access option private module's procedure/function?

Tags: excel, vba

I only know that option private module can hide the procedure/function from the formula tab (prevent user to see it) and can be used in its own project. However, I tried opening another workbook and run the workbook procedure that has option private module declared and it works. Below is my code:

```
Application.Run "Workbook1.xlsm!testing"
```

Also, does add-in can access option private module's procedure/function?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The official documentation of the [Option Private statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-private-statement) says:

> When a module contains `Option Private Module`, the public parts, for example, **variables**, **objects**, and **user-defined types** declared at the module level, are still available within the project containing the module, but they are not available to other applications or projects.

That means public declared variables in a module with `Option Private Module` are only available in the current project but not to other projects. **This does not affect procedures and functions declared as `Public`.** They are still available with `Application.Run "Workbook1.xlsm!testing"`.

The benefit of `Option Private Module` is that you can have a `Public`/`Global` variable in a module that your project can use but no other project can interfere and mess with it.